# How do I delete database records using a Listview control?

Tags: vb.net

**Hello and Good Morning,**

I've been working on a small project to store some data in a MySQL database.  So far I've been able to follow online tutorials and get help with my code from friends and others on this forum.  But now, I want to do something that I can't seem to find any tutorials for.  Hence my coming here.

I have data in a MySQL database and I know how to use a SELECT statement to retrieve the records and assign to a DataTable, then populate the ListView control with the contents of the DataTable.  Now I'd like help on how to delete those records (individually and collectively by use of buttons).  I know the ListView control has a property that allows Checkboxes on each row but I don't know how to use that to select the row(s) I want deleted.  Also, I did some reading and found that I can use the .Remove() method to do this, but how do I pass that back to the database?

If anybody knows a tutorial that can help me, please point me in the right direction.  Alternatively, if you'll be kind enough to assist me here as well, I'd be grateful.

//Kismet

Answer (score 2):

you can use Listview's onitemcommand Event.

Provide your database primary key as dataKeyNames in your Listview.

```
  <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" 
    GroupItemCount="3"  ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" DataKeyNames="Id">
```

Take a linkbutton as your delete button.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeletebtn" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" Font-Underline="true" CommandName="Delete" >Delete</asp:LinkButton>

  protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{       
    if (e.CommandName.ToString()=="Delete")
    {
        //here get your datakey
        string id = listview1.DataKeys[e.ItemIndex].Value.ToString();

           //Now you can fire your delete query 
}
}
```

Comment: Awesome, but how do I do this in Visual Basic?

Comment: you can use converter to convert this code to Vb.Refer this :http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/